# How to do Fourier transform for these 2 questions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation

I don't get certain of parts of these two questions

1)
I'm trying to do the Fourier transform of:
$$f(x) = \, xe^{-x^2} $$

In the problem it said to use:

$$F \, (e^{-tx^2}) = {\sqrt{\frac{π}t}e^{{\frac{-λ^2}{4t}}}} $$

The solution shows this for the first line:

$$F \, (xe^{-x^2}) = F \Big ({-{\frac{1}2}[e^{{{-x^2}}}]'} \Big ) $$

I'm confused about this first part of the solution where it said that it was done by linearity. I don't get how -1/2 came from and how it was derived to get prime('). I do understand what was done afterwards.

2) This is the second problem:
$$f(x) = \, e^{-0.5|x|} $$

in the solution it said:

let $$f(x) = \, e^{-|x|} $$ Then $$F(e^{-0.5|x|}) = \,F (f(0.5x)) = \frac {1}{0.5} \hat{f}(\frac{λ}{0.5}) = \frac{4}{1+4λ^2}$$

I'm confused about how $$\frac {1}{0.5} \hat{f}(\frac{λ}{0.5})= \frac{4}{1+4λ^2}$$ What was done with the $$\hat{f}$$? but I do understand that $$f(x) = \, e^{-|x|} = \frac{2}{1+λ^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

To make Fourier Transforms easy there are a few simple rules like a rule for scaling, modulation, translation and so on. I will use these rules as we go on. They are fundamental when doing Fourier-transforms and you should be familiar with them. Here on the first page you can find many of them http://www.ibk.ethz.ch/ch/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf

In the first example we are going to use the derivation rule:
$$
\mathscr{F}\left(tf(t)\right) = i\frac{d}{d\omega}\mathscr{F}\left(f(t)\right)(\omega)
$$
After applying that you get
$$
\mathscr{F}\left(xe^{-x^2}\right) = i\frac{d}{d\omega}\mathscr{F}\left(e^{-x^2}\right)(\omega)
$$
$\mathscr{F}\left(e^{-x^2}\right)$ can be easily calculated to $\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\omega^2/4}$ and thus Fouriertransform of your problem is
$$
-i\frac{1}{2}\omega\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\omega^2/4}
$$

In the second problem, you have to use the scaling rule that states
$$
\mathscr{F}\left(f(at)\right) = \frac{1}{|{a}|}\mathscr{F}\left(f(t)\right)\left(\frac{\omega}{a}\right)
$$
This means that you have to scale by $a = \frac{1}{2}$
$$
\mathscr{F}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x|}\right) = \frac{1}{\left|{\frac{1}{2}}\right|}\mathscr{F}\left(e^{-|x|}\right)\left(\frac{\omega}{\frac{1}{2}}\right) 
$$
Again, $\mathscr{F}\left(e^{-|x|}\right)$ can be easily calculated to $\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}$, which in the end gives
$$
\mathscr{F}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x|}\right) = \frac{4}{1+4\omega^2}
$$

Comment: In the first problem they used the rule for $\mathcal{F}\left ( \frac{d}{dt} f(t) \right )$. Your method would work too, but it's a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1), note that $f(x) = \frac{-1}{2} (e^{-x^{2}})'$

For Part 2), if $g(\lambda) = \frac{2}{1 + \lambda^{2}}$, then what will 
$2*g(2 \lambda)$ be?